# Multi line label on mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-form-field

I'm trying to display multiple lines on a mat-form-field label.
I tried to use

```
.mat-form-field-label {
   white-space: normal !important;
}
```

[image: With white-space normal]

But that overlaps the input field.
What can I do about that?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

This does not follow the [Material Design](https://material.io/components/text-fields#:%7E:text=Label%20text%20shouldn%E2%80%99t%20take%20up%20multiple%20lines.) and therefore it is not possible to do that with Angular Material.